# How to have Spark application read from an authenticated mongodb with mongo-hadoop connector?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark

I need to read from a mongodb with password from within a Spark application. I used newAPIHadoopRDD() with mongo-hadoop connector. It worked fine with "setMaster('local')", but when I set the spark application to run on "yarn cluster", the application hanged without any error message.

I am using mongo-hadoop-core 1.5.2. Has someone encountered the same issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

mongodbConfig.set("mongo.auth.uri", "mongodb://username:password@192.168.1.1:27017/testdb"),
you can also refer to com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil